# Mysql replication error Last_IO_Error

Tags: mysql, server, replication

We have existing server master to master replication on two server, and we not mentioned 11.12.13.18 ip in any where, but we are getting error like below.

```
Last_IO_Error: Master command COM_REGISTER_SLAVE failed: Access denied for user 'user'@'11.12.13.18' (using password: YES) (Errno: 1045)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You should have your user `user` granted with `REPLICATION SLAVE` privilege. It looks like that you do not have enough privileges set for replication on that user. Try running this on the master:

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'user'@'11.12.13.18';
```